# Recent (help/on-topic) Facelift

Tags: discussion, site-content

To date, we've had some unpleasant Help Center markdown in [help/on-topic](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); if I was a newbie, I wouldn't want to read it.

### Before:

We had

- Bare ALL CAPS headings
- Ugly pastel quote blocks

Added together, it just didn't look appropriate for professional network engineers.

[image]

### After:

I updated [help/on-topic](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) with [more markdown](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/1578/revisions), and direct hyperlinks to where we voted for the on / off-topic material. I also updated with guidance for recommendations and polls, which pop up a lot on the main site.

Hopefully it looks better now...

- Substituted `<h2>` tags for ALL CAPS headings
- Added hyperlinks to where we voted on-topic, in the heading
- Added pop-ups when you hover over the hyperlinks

[image]