# Correcting a spelling error on the "On-Topic" help page

Tags: support, site-content

Sorry to make my first post on this site to Meta, but as I was preparing to ask a question on the main site I stopped by the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help document to make sure my question was going to be on-topic. I noticed a spelling error on this page: "Network" is misspelled in the heading "Off-topic: Users / Customers of Enterprise or Service Provider Netrworks."

[image: Screenshot of spelling error]

I don't know if a new question in Meta is the right place for this note - if it's not I would appreciate your guidance. I saw the [What is ON-topic? Let's improve our FAQ/Help](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/4934) question here but didn't feel like my putting a comment on that post would be productive. If this is something I can edit myself, I'd love to learn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> to make sure my question was going to be on-topic. I noticed a spelling error on this page: "Network" is misspelled in the heading "Off-topic: Users / Customers of Enterprise or Service Provider Netrworks."

I just fixed the typo, and looked for others.  That was my mistake [the last time I edited the document](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/319/775).

> I don't know if a new question in Meta is the right place for this note - if it's not I would appreciate your guidance... If this is something I can edit myself, I'd love to learn!

[Only site moderators and Stack Exchange employees can edit Help Center links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center#comment557276_182819); therefore, meta is certainly the right place to bring this up.  Thank you for pointing the error out.